# I can't remove a package in Django app since it is stored in migrations files

Tags: django

I'm trying to remove ckeditor package in my Django app. I removed ckeditor in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Because of that, I can't run my Django app since ckeditor it throws `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'` in several migrations files, and one of the files looks like the below.

```
import ckeditor_uploader.fields
from django.db import migrations, models
import imagekit.models.fields
import modvisor.blogs.models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('blogs', '0003_auto_20181204_1456'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='article',
            name='headline_image',
            field=imagekit.models.fields.ProcessedImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=modvisor.blogs.models.image_path),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='article',
            name='status',
            field=models.CharField(choices=[('inactive', 'Inactive'), ('active', 'Active')], default='inactive', max_length=20, verbose_name='Showing Status'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='article',
            name='sub_title',
            field=ckeditor_uploader.fields.RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, verbose_name='Sub Title'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='article',
            name='title',
            field=ckeditor_uploader.fields.RichTextUploadingField(),
        ),
    ]
```

My Django app has a production DB and server in AWS. I've searched about deleting migrations files, and most of people say it depends, but not recommended especially when it has production DB.

Without touching the migrations files, how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried [squashing migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations)? If it's able to create new migrations that don't reference the removed package then you have a safe path to deleting the old migrations.

Comment: I haven't tried squashing. I'm gonna look into it. Thanks. By the way, is it never gonna be a good idea to remove migration files in any case?

Comment: The documentation addresses deleting the replaced migration files. The only question is whether the autodetector is smart enough to create a set of squashed migrations that doesn't include the package.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry You are right. The migration optimizer did not remove the package from squashed migration.